Как разместить картинку и список в одну линию ? Без float


* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

nav {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

.navdiv ul,
a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  gap: 15px;
}

.navdiv li a {
  font-weight: 800;
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  &:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    translate: 40px 20px;
  }
}

.navdiv img {
  width: 300px;
}
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navdiv">
      <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
      <ul class="list">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>




Не смог добавить часть с css)

для .navdiv display: flex

она стоит  *************** * {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
max-width: 1440px;
margin:0;
padding:0 15px;
}
nav {
background-color: #D3D3D3;
}
.navdiv ul,a {
display:flex;
justify-content: flex-end;
align-items: center;
list-style: none;
gap:15px;
}
.navdiv li a {
font-weight: 800;
transition:0.5s;
text-decoration: none;
color:black;
&:hover {
background-color:  blue;
translate:40px 20px;
}

}
.navdiv img {
width:300px;
}

они не на одной линии ,  листы снизу а картинка сверху , нужно чтобы они были  на одной линии

Внимательно посмотрите на свои стили и что написал я.

@OliverPatterson спасибо все получилось )
